# iOS app publishing - publishing under different author name

Tags: iphone, ios, app-store, publishing

I have been developing and testing an iPhone app under a family members Apple Developer account. He paid for the account and it's registered under his business.

When it comes time to publish, will it appear in the App store (and for that matter anywhere else where the author name is published), under his name or his company name?

Can this be changed? Is it possible to publish an app on a developer account but under a different author name?

Comment: Why not just buy your own account

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it will appear in the App Store under his name (if registered as an individual) or his company name (if he's registered as a company).

Answer (score 1):

> Can this be changed? Is it possible to publish an app on a developer
>   account but under a different author name?

No, and no. The name the developer account is registered to is the name that appears in the App Store for any apps published by that developer account.

Answer (score 1):

If the person named on an individual iOS developer enrollment incorporates an app business and obtains a DUNS number for that corporation, Apple may allow changing the developer account to a company enrollment using that corporation's legal name.  This would then allow publishing apps in the App Store under that corporation's name, instead of under the original individual's name.

Answer (score 0):

It will appear under the account used to submit the app. It's possible to develop it under one account and submit it under another, but that's the only way to change the displayed author name.

Note that if you did a partial submission with one account, you won't be able to easily reuse the app name: you'll have to wait for it to expire on the first account, wait some unknown amount of time for it to become available again, and then register it under the second account before anyone else does.

If you've not locked down the name with the first account, though, there's nothing to it.