# Publish iOS application with different name

Tags: ios, app-store

We created an app for iOS and now we want to publish this app. We want to publish with different name, We dont want to use my name or the name of my college.

During the process, Can I specific the name that will appear under the application under the app in apple store?

I read this thread: [iOS app publishing - publishing under different author name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7796673/ios-app-publishing-publishing-under-different-author-name)

are there any change? or still we cant publish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there has been no change.

It sounds like you haven't published your app yet, if that is the case you can create a second apple ID, make a second developer account under a new name and publish it without issue. It will obviously cost for another developer account. I have 3 accounts, one personal and two for work, and have had no problem.

If you have published the app already, you can change the name on the developer account. I have also done this. It took about month to fully complete.

Comment: If I create another account with a group name, and the credit card is titled under my name, this wont create problem?

Comment: Nope. When you purchase the developer account it gets added to your cart just like when you buy a sweater from amazon. Then when you checkout you are asked to login with your Apple ID. This doesn't have to be the same Apple ID that you are linking to the developer account. In my case I pay for the developer account with a completely different Apple ID (my personal one) then the Apple ID I use to manager our company account.